# Python calling PUT request : 'PUT' not supported

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to call an API on a 3rd party application (Qlik Catalog).

They provide a Swagger page where I have tested the call, and it provides a curl:

```
curl 
-X PUT "http://xxxxnnnnnn.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:nnnn/qdc/entity/v1/loadDataForEntities/true" 
-H "accept: */*" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: xnxnxnxn-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" 
-d "[{\"entityId\":\"1234\",\"loadType\":\"OVERWRITE\",\"loadTime\":\"123456789012\"}]"
```

I am implementing this via Python but getting:

> Request method 'PUT' not supported

Any ideas what the problem might be ??
Thanks

Code below (with lots of debug printing!):

```
url_stem = 'http://xxxxnnnnnn.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:nnnn/qdc/entity/v1/loadDataForEntities/true'
payload = [{"entityId":"1234","loadType":"OVERWRITE","loadTime":"123456789012"}] 
headers = {'accept': '*/*','Content-type': 'application/json','X-XSRF-TOKEN':'xnxnxnxn-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'}      

print('-------------------------')
print('[Sending]..')
print('    url: %s' % (url_stem))
print('    payload: %s' % (payload))
print('    headers: %s' % (session.headers))
print('    cookies: %s' % (session.cookies))

response = session.put(url_stem, json=payload, headers=headers)

print('-------------------------')
print('    Reponse.....')
print('        [Status]:%s' % response)
print('        [response json]: %s' % response.json())
print('        [rsp:Headers]:%s' % response.headers)
print('-------------------------')
```

And the CMD output:

```
[Sending]..
    url: http://xxxxnnnnnn.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:nnnn/qdc/entity/v1/loadDataForEntities/true
    payload: [{'entityId': '1234', 'loadType': 'OVERWRITE', 'loadTime': '123456789012'}]
    headers: {
    'accept': '*/*', 
    'Content-type': 'application/json', 
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
    }
    sess cooks: <RequestsCookieJar[
    <Cookie JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for xxxxnnnnnn.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/qdc>, 
    <Cookie XSRF-TOKEN=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx for xxxxnnnnnn.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/qdc>
    ]>
-------------------------
Reponse.....
[Status]:<Response [405]>
[response json]: {
    'code': 'DYNAMIC_ERROR', 
    'fullCode': 'pgui.error.code.DYNAMIC_ERROR', 
    'message':"pgui.error.code.DYNAMIC_ERROR - Request method 'PUT' not supported",
    'localizedMessage': "pgui.error.code.DYNAMIC_ERROR - Request method 'PUT' not supported"
}
 [rsp:Headers]:{
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 
    'X-XSS-Protection': '1; 
mode=block', 
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 
    'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
    'Expires': '0', 
    'Content-Security-Policy': "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; block-all-mixed-content", 
    'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 
    'Permissions-Policy': 'geolocation=(),camera=()', 
    'vary': 'accept-encoding', 
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 
    'Date': 'Tue, 24 Aug 2021 13:45:19 GMT', 
    'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=20', 
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your python code that throws the error?

Comment: .. is in the code above. "response = session.put(url_stem, json=payload, headers=headers)"

Comment: Have you tried running the curl command on the commandline? If this fails you might have an issue with the network. If curl works then you will have to find what difference there is between the curl- and the requests-call. Perhaps using [curlify](https://github.com/ofw/curlify). It looks like you did everything correctly though.